# Importing project spring-boot in IntelliJ IDEA error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm importing `spring-boot` web maven project in `IntelliJ`, My project has worked in `Eclipse` and `STS` tool.
I have an error below:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50562:/Applications/IntelliJ 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help to resolve it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is it web project? Was this built on eclipse?

Comment: Yes. It's worked in eclipse and STS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you forgot to add `Servlet` related dependencies in your project, specially when you import a project which was built on Eclipse where you have option to attach server(like Apache Tomcat) in project Build Path.

So in new IDE(in your case IntelliJ) also, you have to do the same, but I suggest add the required dependencies then it will work with all IDEs.

Try adding below dependencies in your project `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Dependencies version you can change as per project requirement.

Alternatively if project has `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency then make sure it should scoped as `compile` like below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I have just added dependencies above and re-build after that run it but I also meet the error.

Comment: Does pom.xml has spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency with scope?

Comment: Yes. I have added tomcat embedded in pom file.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. I have just change from provide to compile, it's worked. So kindly you explain why to me understand deep of it?

Comment: compile scope means compile dependencies are available in classpath of project even when you run but provided dependencies will not be available at runtime maven expects JDK or other container to provide those dependencies at runtime. If those are not provided you will get errors.

Comment: If this answer helped then you can accept my answer so that could help others in the community.

Comment: Thank again, I will do it.